# Binding radio buttons to specific enum values in Spring Webflow

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, spring-webflow

In my Spring Webflow (with JSP views) I have a model that contains an enum for one of its fields. I need a form with a set of radio buttons that contain only a couple of those possible enum values and I can't seem to crack how to do it.

So my flow is something like this:

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="someService.getModel()" result="flowScope.myModel" />
</on-start>

<view-state id="step1" view="step1View" model="myModel">
    <transition on="proceed" to="step2"/>
</view-state>
```

And myModel has a field called "paymentType" which is an enum (called PaymentType) that could look soemthing like this:

```
public enum PaymentType{

    RE("A paper reciept"),

    CC("Credit Card"),

    PA("Pre-Authorised Debit"),

    MC("MyCoin"),

    private final String shortDescription;

    PaymentOptionType(final String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }
}
```

So let's say in my step1 page I only want to put 2 of these values on the form.
So it would look like:

```
* A paper reciept
* MyCoin
|Submit|
```

And it would bind the selected value to the paymentType field in the model.

So I'm wondering how to populate the radio buttons in my form in step1.jsp

```
<form:form id="paymentForm" name="paymentForm" modelAttribute="myModel" method="post" action="${flowExecutionUrl}"> 
    <!-- What to put for radio buttons here? -->                
    <button name="_eventId_proceed">Next Step</button>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<form:radiobutton path="paymentType" value="RE"/>A paper receipt
<form:radiobutton path="paymentType" value="MC"/>My Coin
..
```

or add something like this to your flow

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="someService.getPaymentTypes()" result="flowScope.paymentTypes" />
</on-start>
```

and then use

```
<c:forEach var="paymentType" items="${paymentTypes}>
    <form:radiobutton path="paymentType" value="${paymentType}"/>${paymentType.shortDescription}
</c:forEach>
```